# Сгруппировать данные в RecyclerView и вывести то, из-за чего они группируются

Tags: android, recyclerview

Предположим, есть JSON-данные вот такого типа:

```
{
    "fruits": [
        {
            "pk": 2616,
            "type": "apple"
            "info": "Red Apple"
        },
        {
            "pk": 2615,
            "type": "orange"
            "info": "Sweet Orange"
        },
        {
            "pk": 2614,
            "type": "apple",
            "info": "Green Apple"
        },
        {
            "pk": 2617,
            "type": "orange"
            "info": "Blue Orange"
        },
    ]
},
```

Необходимо сгруппировать их, скажем, по полю `type` и вывести их в `RecyclerView`, при этом "сгенерировать" под каждым сгруппированным списком значение этого поля (или иными словами - создать header для каждого из них).

Вот так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На данный момент есть идея фильтровать все JSON-данные в `HashMap` вот таким образом: 
 
Создать лист `ArrayList<HashMap<String, ArrayList<Fruits>>>`. В `onBindViewHolder()` методе класса RecycleAdapter уже вытаскивать их по такому принципу:

```
public class RecycleAdapter {

    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, Fruits>> fruits = new ArrayList<>();

    // ...

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        HashMap<String, Fruits> current = fruits.get(position); 

        for (Map.Entry<String, Fruits> entry : current.entrySet()) {
            String type = entry.getKey();
            Fruits fruit = entry.getValue();
            // Далее беру fruit.getInfo() и ставлю ее в holder.
        }
    }
}
```

C этим более менее разобрался, но далее встает вопрос: как вывести тот самый ключ `type` в `TextView`, под каждым из этих листов соответственно?

Comment: вам нужно именно несколько отдельных списков с заголовком их типа в отдельном виджете (каждый тип скролится отдельно, а заголовок не скролится) или все же один список (все типы и их заголовки скролятся вместе)?

Comment: @pavlofff вообще, лучше в отдельном варианте. Потому что когда будет много элементов, будет удобнее скролить отдельно каждый тип)

Answer (score 2):

Допустим Ваши модели можно получить через метод `getFruits()`:

**Шаг 1:** `YourTypeCompator` - необходимо реализовать компаратор который будет сортировать ваши фрукты по типу.

```
public class YourTypeCompator extends Comparator<Fruits> {
    public int compare(final Fruits o1, final Fruits o2) {
        return o1.getType().compateTo(o2);
    }
}
```

и сортируем список:

```
ArrayList<Fruits> fruits = getFruits();
Collections.sort(fruits, new YourTypeCompator());
```

**Шаг 2:** Далее создаем модели для `RecyclerView`, для упрощения будет использована библиотека [RendererRecyclerViewAdapter](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter):

Модель которая будет хранить название фрукта и другие данные если это необходимо:

```
public class FruitModel implements ViewModel {
    String getName() { ... }
}
```

Модель которая будет отвечать тип фрукта:

```
public class FruitTypeModel implements ViewModel {
    String getName() { ... }
}
```

`ViewModel` - пустой интерфейс из библиотеки

**Шаг 3:** Создаем `ViewBinder` для каждой модели:

Биндер для ячейки фрукта:

```
public ViewBinder getFruitViewBinder() {
    return new ViewBinder<>(
        R.layout.fruit_item, //xml вашей ячейки фрукта
        FruitModel.class //класс вышесозданной ячейки
        (model, finder, payload) -> {
            finder.setText(R.id.fruit_title, model.getName())
            //ваш биндинг ячейки
        }
    );
}
```

Биндер для ячейки типа фрукта:

```
public ViewBinder getFruitTypeViewBinder() {
    return new ViewBinder<>(
        R.layout.fruit_type_item, //xml вашей ячейки типа фрукта
        FruitTypeModel.class //класс вышесозданной ячейки
        (model, finder, payload) -> {
            finder.setText(R.id.fruit_type_title, model.getName())
            //ваш биндинг ячейки
        }
    );
}
```

**Шаг 4:** Мапим старый список моделей в новый:

```
ArrayList<Fruits> fruits = getFruits();
Collections.sort(fruits, new YourTypeCompator());

ArrayList<ViewModel> newModels = new ArrayList<>();
String previousFruitType = "";

for(Fruits model: fruits) {
    if(!model.getType().equals(previousFruitType)) {
        //если сменился тип - добавляем ячейку типа
        newModels.add(new FruitTypeModel(model.getInfo()));
        previousFruitType = model.getType();
    }
    newModels.add(new FruitModel(model.getInfo()));
}
```

В результате получаем список вида:

```
0 Apple Type
1 Red Apple
2 Green Apple
3 Orange
4 Sweet Orange
5 Blue Orange
```

**Шаг 5:** Инициализируем адаптер и передаем ему необходимые данные

```
RendererRecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RendererRecyclerViewAdapter();

adapter.registerRenderer(getFruitViewBinder()); //регистрируем вышесозданный рендерер
adapter.registerRenderer(getFruitTypeViewBinder()); //регистрируем вышесозданный рендерер

adapter.setItems(newModels); //передаем новый список
```

**Заключение:** В итоге получаем отсортированный список фруктов перед каждой категорией будет еще одна ячейка с названием.

Если необходимо категории разделить по отдельным RecyclerView - посмотрите в сторону [CompositeViewBinder](https://github.com/vivchar/RendererRecyclerViewAdapter/wiki/Quick-start-with-Composite-Items)